# Use of undeclared identifier 'kUTTypeURL'

Tags: ios, objective-c, undeclared-identifier

In Actions extension I got this error "Use of undeclared identifier 'kUTTypeURL' ". I imported mobile core services(in class and linked libraries also). But again it shows error. In simulator I am not getting this error.But in devices I got this. Previously few weeks back its worked fine. Right now I got this.I already seen " Use of undeclared identifier 'kUTTypeMovie' ". But its not worked me. In Xcode 9.1 its working good. In Xcode 9.2 I got this error. I am not sure this issue is related to Xcode. I got this error in Xcode 9.2 and iOS 11.2.1.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't know why it happens. But finally got the answer. In Xcode 9.2 UTCoreTypes.h shows empty. So I opened it in Xcode 9.1, copied UICoreType.h content and pasted it in Xcode 9.2.